# Tone of Voice when speaking to audience

Tags: user-behavior, user-expectation, user-research, experience, tone-of-voice

Working on a new homepage for my site and my primary audience is developers.

In my title I was planning on using something like...

```
Helping </developers> achieve their potential
```

The markup above is invalid and I'm wondering if this could breed a sense of frustration, or that I don't understand my audience?

```
/* Helping Developers */
Achieve your potential with our libraries
```

The above is more in keeping and adheres to coding standards - what are your thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Just move the slash to before the closing right arrow and you're done with valid markup. You're right in that I, too, paused at seeing the slash in the wrong place.

The second is halting as a comment getting in the way of reading.

When reading code, I sometimes don't get too interrupted by markup such as yours but comments should pause what I'm reading.

Comment: Thanks Rob, I don't mind so much people pausing to read comments as it's only ever going to appear as a subtitle. The </Comment> could still be invalid however as I'd intend to use it </in examples like this> - guess I need to speak to more of the audience!